# Bidirectional databinding with RealmObject. Transaction requirement

Tags: android, realm, android-databinding

I want to use `RealmObject` as view model in databinding layout of `RecycleView` item. Some of properties must be bidirectional binded to the view - such as `AppCompatCheckBox`. But when databinding execute setter's callback, next exception is occur:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.

#### Which way is better to open Realm transaction for bidirectional databinding?

**item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="shoppingItem"
            type="com.example.ShoppingListItem"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/product_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{shoppingItem.product.title}"
            android:checked="@={shoppingItem.purchased}"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

**ShoppingListItem.java**

```
public class ShoppingListItem extends RealmObject implements Identifiable {

    @PrimaryKey private long id;
    private Product product;
    private boolean manual;
    private boolean purchased;

    @Override public long getId() { return id; }
    @Override public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Product getProduct() { return product; }
    public void setProduct(Product product) { this.product = product; }

    public boolean isManual() { return manual; }
    public void setManual(boolean manual) { this.manual = manual; }

    public boolean isPurchased() { return purchased; }
    public void setPurchased(boolean purchased) { this.purchased = purchased; }
}
```

Comment: [Don't use Managed RealmProxies for Data Binding. Managed RealmObjects/RealmResults are immutable view of the data, You should save them to Realm only when the modifications are complete.](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/realm-1-2-0-android-data-binding-1dc06822287f)